# How I can use of Wordnet to POS text files in matlab?

Tags: nlp, matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

I want to POS tagging my text files in matlab ... please let me know how I can do it?

I would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a detailed description of using matlab with the stanford max entropy pos-tagger: 
http://utkarshu.in/Easy_POS_tagging.html

It doesn't use wordnet but will work for pos-tagging.

Hope this helps!

---

edit...
You don't need to know java to make this work, but you should have java installed (if you don't already see https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml and follow the directions).  If you have java installed, simply follow the directions in the matlab interface:

> It requires the following files:
>       1. left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger in the current path while running it. It can be found in      $STANFORD_POS_TAGGER_PATH/models/
>       2. stanford-postagger.jar should be added to the classpath.
>           Matlab command to do it:
>
> ```
> javaaddpath('$STANFORD_POS_TAGGER_PATH/stanford-postagger.jar')
> ```
>
> To run it simple use: PosTaggerM(sample_sentence)

so just make sure that whatever directory you are in when you run matlab, "left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger" is also in that directory.  then add the tagger to your classpath and use the command to run it.  good luck.

Comment: I am trying to use standford POS tagger in matlab  , but unfortunately I could not , may because I dont know java. but I read the standford page and I put "stanford-postagger-2014-01-04" folder in my matlab forlder and then put the copy of "left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger" and "stanford-postagger.jar" in my direct path. but I dont know is it enough or not ? and how can I use it . I would appreciate your help.